My topic should not have been closed
Moderators:  someone closed my post about storing a chandelier by suspending it from the walls.  It was classified as "interior decorating."  This is NOT about decorating.  It's about storage.  Just happens to be a chandelier.  I need advice about weight bearing anchors, shear, toggles, beams, etc.  Take a look at the post!  I need the advice of people who know how tools and physics work, not how colors and fabrics (etc etc) go together.   :-\

I wonder if the "I want to display it" comment perhaps made the question look like artwork display ?

I completely agree, and I've commented to that effect and voted to reopen.

IDK.  While her OP doesn't say the chandelier will be wired up, it says "mount," which to me says it's a permanent installation, which at least implies electrical connection—not "storage."

It was quite clear in the inital post. I don't know at what point it was closed .vs. at what point the text making it clear that it was about storing a non-working chandelier happened. Both the non-working and can't mount to ceiling parts are relevant, but have been removed in edits. There have been some fairly thoughtless close votes on clear questions lately, IMHO.
